# matching selected apostrophes with regex

Tags: regex

i am trying to change the " in the title below to a single quote while leaving the other " as they are.  It seems that the " with letters on each side is what i need to select, and the " with a space on one side or the other should be left alone. After making the change i am saving the edited file...any help would be appreciated ( my workaround is to use an * for the apostrophe in the title and change that to a single apostrophe)

```
<img src="_slideshow/080.jpg" alt="8" title="...the wicked witch"s complexion was green"/>
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: You've said what should happens to quotes with letters on both sides, and what should happen to quotes with a space on one side or the other. What about all the other possibilities though?

Comment: FYI, in html, you __can't__ have literal double quotes in attribute values.

Comment: So, how did you end up in this messy situation?

Comment: i am doing this in php. i started with a flash slide show with xml data and a jquery "gallery" that  lets you change the image order and captions inreal time online....i am changing this to work on the iphone with javascript....this is my first try. i have an inelegant solution that doesn't take care of all situations:

Answer (score 1):

Some languages support fixed width negative lookbehinds. If yours does then you can use this:

```
/(?<!\s)"(?!\s)/
```

The token `\s` matches any whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The regex:

```
/(\w)"(\w)/\1'\2/g
```

would do it

Comment: While this is the right answer for what you asked for, as Mark Byer's questions suggest... you may not be asking the right question

Comment: The lookaround version can handle `a"b"c`, while this approach doesn't.